# What is the Azure equivalent of GCP's Cloud Run?

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-web-app-service, google-cloud-run

I'm looking for an equivalent to Cloud Run (GCP offering) in Azure

In particular:

1. It deploys a container
2. Can scale down to 0
3. Can serve a webapp

Does Azure have such a service?

I was looking at Azure App Service, but it seems to be missing the ability to scale down to 0.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Azure Container Apps is similar to GCP Cloud Run.

- It deploys a container: **yes**
- Can scale down to 0: **yes**
- Can serve a webapp: **yes**

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-apps/

Comment: ACI is also a good product.

Answer (score 4):

I think the equivalent of Cloud Run would be Azure Container Instances rather than Azure Container Apps.
I would say Azure Container Apps would be the equivalent of App Engine from Google Cloud which comes with more managed services around the served container like authentication, etc...

Comment: Not sure I can agree with this. As is explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/compare-options#azure-container-instances and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/compare-options#azure-container-apps we can find most options that are available in GCP Cloud Run in the ACA: microservice approach, scale up or down to 0, traffic split, revisions, ...